# Product of Strouhal and Mach number

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, physical-constants

Is there any common interpretation of the product of Strouhal and Mach number? (Such as Roshko number is a product of Strouhal and Reynolds numbers describing vortex shedding).

Note: I am asking for literature reference. The basic operations with the definitions are obvious.

Comment: I've never seen that used before, but you would end up with a ratio of your unsteadiness to the acoustic velocity ($\text{St} = fL/u$ and $\text{M} = u/c \rightarrow \text{St}\text{M} = fL/c$). Could be a useful metric in conditions where you are looking at acoustic coupling. Like a vibration/shedding cycling locking into an acoustic mode of a duct. I imagine it's only useful for confined flows though. External flows don't have acoustic modes usually due to the infinite domains.

Comment: The shockwave tag was misplaced. I have cleared that out.

Comment: That's what I suspected... Do you have a particular application in mind? The only thing I can think of is what I mentioned in the earlier comment -- it might be useful to characterize your hydrodynamic frequencies/time scales to the acoustic frequencies/time scales.

Comment: That's basically my concern. I came to that during equations scaling. I just don't thing I am the first one to arrive at such term (too simple not to be explored).

Comment: [This is a pretty comprehensive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_numbers_in_fluid_mechanics) and I don't see it on there. But, maybe somebody else has come across it. It's possible it's simple enough that nobody bothered naming it. Hopefully somebody else will see this who might know of it.